# excel vba hardening a fragile function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I've created a spreadsheet for tracking student data for my wife. There are 2 versions, the master and the teacher version. The only difference is that the teacher version has a couple of tabs and buttons hidden.

At the end of every day she gathers the teacher versions and merges their data into the master version using a macro attached to a button. On a regular basis it causes Excel to crash. It seems like trying to merge a workbook that is on a usb stick is a surefire way to make it crash, but there are other circumstances that I haven't identified yet.

She isn't technical enough to step through the code until it blows and I can't be there when she is doing it.

Previous attempts to harden the code involved getting rid of any instance of Activesheet or Activeworkbook, and always using a direct reference to the worksheet (ie Sheet1, but renamed to something meaningful - "merge" in the example below).

The function below, LoadTeacherData, is called once for each workbook to merge. All it does is copy the existing records on the teacher's data tab, copy them to the master merge tab and then delete them from the source. When it crashes it is immediately after selecting the file to load, I think.

```
Sub LoadTeacherData()
Dim wb_td As Workbook
Dim td As Worksheet
Dim newdata As Range

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xlsm"

    If .Show = -1 Then
        file_name = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wb_td = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=file_name, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=False)
If wb_td Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Unable to open file, check path", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

file_name = wb_td.Name
Set td = wb_td.Worksheets("data")

row = LastRow(td, "C")
col = LastCol(td, 1)
Set newdata = td.Range("a2", td.Cells(row, col))
newdata.Copy Destination:=Merge.Cells(LastRow(Merge, "C") + 1, 1)
newdata.Clear
MsgBox (row - 1 & " records merged")
wb_td.Close
ThisWorkbook.Activate
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub


Function LastRow(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByVal colname As String)
    LastRow = ws.Range(colname & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
End Function

Function LastCol(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByVal rownum As Long)
    LastCol = ws.Cells(rownum, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End Function
```

My suspicion is that it has something to do with permissions when opening the file. Her excel version is configured so that she has to enable content every time when opening a file.

Comment: Does she ever see the `"Unable to open file, check path"` message box before it crashes? I suspect based on your description that you just need an error trap around the `Set wb_td = Workbooks.Open` line.

Comment: You can establish some form of logging so you can debug later. Refine it over time. I guess it partly depends on what you mean by crash.

Comment: @Comintern no she never gets the error message.

Comment: @QHarr  I mean that Excel completely crashes. It has to be opened again.

Answer (score 0):

You may be dealing with a corrupted file.  [Look at the workbooks.open method.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbooks.Open) There are a few options under corruptload that may help. Try this one and experiment to see if any of the others work better in your situation.

```
Set wb_td = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=file_name, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=False, corruptload:=xlRepairFile)
```

Comment: I don't think it is a corrupt file issue. In the USB stick scenario it generally will load after copying it to the hard drive.